# pg replication connection not returns wal events to java code client , it hangs some times

Tags: postgresql, java

Describe the issue
We are facing issue of pg replication slot not listen database wal events.
Once pg database restarted and we attach

- Driver Version: 42.2.6
- Java Version: JDK1.8
- OS Version: Window 10
- PostgreSQL Version: 9.6

Steps to reproduce the behaviour:

Code using [the sample from the JDBC driver's documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/replication.html#physical-replication)

Created replication connection logical with test decode

```java
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://dbhist8:port/" + db;
Properties props = new Properties();
PGProperty.USER.set(props, "postgres");
PGProperty.PASSWORD.set(props, "postgres");
PGProperty.ASSUME_MIN_SERVER_VERSION.set(props, "10.5");
PGProperty.REPLICATION.set(props, "database");
PGProperty.PREFER_QUERY_MODE.set(props, "simple");
Connection slotVerifyConnection = null;
Connection slotConnection = null;
try {
//TODO connection pool
slotVerifyConnection = connect(url, "postgres", "postgres");
slotConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
Statement statement = slotVerifyConnection.createStatement();
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("select restart_lsn,active,active_pid from pg_replication_slots where slot_type = 'logical' and slot_name ='" + slotName + "'");
while (result.next()) {

            lastLSNNumber = LogSequenceNumber.valueOf(result.getString(1));

        }

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        PGConnection replConnection = con.unwrap(PGConnection.class);

        PGReplicationStream stream = null;


        if (lastLSNNumber != null) {
            stream =
                    replConnection.getReplicationAPI()
                            .replicationStream()
                            .logical()
                            .withSlotName(slotName)
                            //.withSlotOption("include-xids", true)
                             //.withSlotOption("skip-empty-xacts", true)
                            .withStartPosition(lastLSNNumber)

                            // .withStatusInterval(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .withStatusInterval(Integer.parseInt("0"), TimeUnit.SECONDS).start();
        } else {

            **ReplicationSlotInfo info=       replConnection.getReplicationAPI()
                    .createReplicationSlot()
                    .logical()
                    .withSlotName(slotName)
                    .withOutputPlugin(wal2json)
                    .make();**
            info.getConsistentPoint();
            stream =
                    replConnection.getReplicationAPI()
                            .replicationStream()
                            .logical()
                            .withSlotName(slotName)
                        //    .withSlotOption("include-xids", false)
                       //     .withSlotOption("skip-empty-xacts", true)
                            .withStatusInterval(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .start();
        }
        while (true) {
            //non blocking receive message
            ByteBuffer msg = stream.read();

            if (msg == null) {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10L);
                continue;
            }

            int offset = msg.arrayOffset();
            byte[] source = msg.array();
            int length = source.length - offset;
            System.out.println(new String(source, offset, length));
            String sql=new String(source, offset, length);
            //QueryUtils.getQueries(sql);
            if(stream.getLastReceiveLSN()!=null) {
                stream.setAppliedLSN(stream.getLastReceiveLSN());
                stream.setFlushedLSN(stream.getLastReceiveLSN());
                stream.forceUpdateStatus();
            }else{
                System.out.println("NULL value");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: Your link is to the section on physical replication, but you seem to be talking about logical replication.  Also, please post code that compiles.

Comment: guys, issue is clear using maven dependency and example  https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/replication.html#physical-replication we are trying run logical replication but slots created on db, BUT ISSUE WE ARE NOT GETTING events of wals

Comment: I am able to fix issue , this is due to jdbc wal slot creation issue, I am creating slot now using SQL command not with JDBC api which fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed issue using SQL slot creation sql command.
Removed below code which blocks executions 
     **ReplicationSlotInfo info=       replConnection.getReplicationAPI()
                    .createReplicationSlot()
                    .logical()
                    .withSlotName(slotName)
                    .withOutputPlugin(wal2json)
                    .make();**

And my issue was fixed.
Let me know if anyone face same issue I can help.